# Find all combinations of a Polars Dataframe selecting one element from each row

Tags: python, combinations, python-polars

I have a Polars Dataframe, and I would like to contrust a new Dataframe that consists of all possible combinations choosing 1 element from each row.

Visually like so:

An input Dataframe

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| A1       | B1       | C1       |
| A2       | B2       | C2       |
| A3       | B3       | C3       |
```

would give

```
| Column A | Column B | Column A |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| A1       | A2       | A3       |
| A1       | A2       | B3       |
| A1       | A2       | C3       |
| A1       | B2       | A3       |
| A1       | B2       | B3       |
| A1       | B2       | C3       |
| A1       | C2       | A3       |
| A1       | C2       | B3       |
| A1       | C2       | C3       |
| B1       | A2       | A3       |
| B1       | A2       | B3       |
| B1       | A2       | C3       |
| B1       | B2       | A3       |
| B1       | B2       | B3       |
| B1       | B2       | C3       |
| B1       | C2       | A3       |
| B1       | C2       | B3       |
| B1       | C2       | C3       |
```

etc...

I have tried to implement this by simply using a 2D array and a double for loop which is fairly simple, however, I would really like to implment this using Polars' Dataframes and being compliant with the way Polars is built as I'm hoping it can compute much faster than a double for loop would. This library is still fairly new to me so please let me know if there is some kind of misunderstanding on my end.

Comment: I don't really understand the structure of the output. If column `A` is of type string and `B` is of type `int`, should column `A` in the resulting table contain mixed types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct "combinations" functionality as far as I am aware.

One possible approach is to `.implode()` then `.explode()` each column.

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Column A ┆ Column B ┆ Column C │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ A1       ┆ B1       ┆ C1       │
│ A2       ┆ B2       ┆ C2       │
│ A3       ┆ B3       ┆ C3       │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
""")
```

```py
(df.select(pl.all().implode())
   .explode("Column A")
   .explode("Column B")
   .explode("Column C")
)
```

```
shape: (27, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Column A ┆ Column B ┆ Column C │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ A1       ┆ B1       ┆ C1       │
│ A1       ┆ B1       ┆ C2       │
│ A1       ┆ B1       ┆ C3       │
│ A1       ┆ B2       ┆ C1       │
│ …        ┆ …        ┆ …        │
│ A3       ┆ B2       ┆ C3       │
│ A3       ┆ B3       ┆ C1       │
│ A3       ┆ B3       ┆ C2       │
│ A3       ┆ B3       ┆ C3       │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

You can add [`.unique()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.unique.html#polars.Expr.unique) in the case of any duplicate values.

Instead of having to name each column, you could use the Lazy API and a loop:

```py
out = df.lazy().select(pl.all().implode())
for col in df.columns:
    out = out.explode(col)
    
out.collect()
```

Comment: The implode then explode method worked great! Although I had to transpose the dataframe before doing so to get the desired result.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @RyanXu Maybe you can show the original dataframe because `.transpose()` is a pretty costly operation. There may be a better way.